# equivalent of startactivity & finish in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to replace viewcontroller (same as startactivity & finish or window.location.replace)

How do I replace viewcontroller instead of push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's multiple ways to implement this based on your view controller containments. If you have the current view controller on top of the stack of a `UINavigationController`, then below is one solution:

```
UINavigationController
  -- root view controller
  -- view controller 2
  -- view controller 3
  -- other view controllers in stack
  -- view controller n - 1
  -- view controller n
```

You want to replace `view controller n` with another view controller (instance).

Declare a delegate on `view controller n`'s class, it set `view controller n - 1` to conform that delegate. When you push `view controller n`, you set `view controller n - 1` to its `delegate`.

When you want to replace `view controller n`, you call the `delegate` method from it, passing necessary parameters to construct the new view controller. Then inside `view controller n - 1`, you tell `UINavigationController` to pop the current top view controller (`view controller n`) and push the new view controller.

Another solution is to send notification to UINavigationController to pop and push.

`UINavigationController` has several useful methods when you want to change the view stack:

- `setViewControllers` (another one with animation param is also available)
- `popToViewController`

Not very flexible, but just one way to do so.