# Reload a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to reload a `ViewController` in my iOS application. I did some researches and the answer is always `[self viewdidload]` or `setNeedsDisplay();` but in my case I need to reload everything ( init , loadView and viewDidLoad)

I wrote a function for reload :

```
- (void)reload{
    [self init];
    [self loadView];
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

but I got a warning

> “expression result unused”

. It works but I think that it's not the right thing to do. Any suggestions ?

this my view controller's code :

```
-(id) init {

    switch (_route) {

        case ROUTE_GPS:
            baseController = [[GpsController alloc] init];
            _key = KEY_GPS;
            break;

        case ROUTE_TEST:
            baseController = [[TestController alloc] init];
            _key = KEY_TEST;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return [super init];
}

-(void) loadView {
    [super loadView];
    [baseController initView:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(update:) name:_key object:nil];
}
```

Comment: yeah its not right thing to do. I gave you one idea like you can take a scrollview for it and refreshcontrol on scrollview So, when refreshcontrol's method called, in that method you can reload your view as well

Comment: the issue is that I don't want to reload only the view . I want to reload all even the variables which exist in init function

Comment: you can reload anything or any method or as you want to update in that method

Comment: still I don't want to use scrollview

Comment: ok,then it's your choice.

Comment: check this ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558635/equivalent-of-startactivity-finish-in-ios

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}

-(void)reloadView
{
    [self configureView];
}

-(void)configureView
{
    variable1 = something;
    variable2 = somethingElse;
}

-(void)atSomeOtherPointInTime
{
    [self reloadView];
}
```

You should not call view controller's life cycle functions yourself, like `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) you should **never** call the loadView method.

> You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls
>   this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil.
>   This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view
>   property.

Comment: yes but I need something like startActivity in android

Comment: In that case, you can create a parent view controller and add the view controller you want to reload as a child of parent view controller.